# Unable to pass controller and directive scope into child directive using require

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I am trying to pass the controller scope of parent controller and parent directive into a child directive but facing an error saying that the controller is not available. Here is a plunk for that

http://plnkr.co/edit/aahgOK9oFFjcP2y5VkVa?p=preview

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
    <new-dir>
      <data-customer-details customer="mc.customers[0]" logger="mc.logger()" version-age="{{mc.age}}"></data-customer-details>
    </new-dir>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I tinkered with your plunker a bit.  I couldn't get it working using Controller As...I had to change it over to $scope injection on the main controller.  Then I created a new scope on newDir by setting `scope: true`.

You don't actually need to require the MainCtrl because these directives are automatically children of that scope anyway.

I changed your 'MainCtrl' to this:

```
  angular.module('plunker').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'World';

    $scope.customers = [{
      "name": "angularjs 1.4",
      "version": "1.4"
    }, {
      "name": "angularjs 1.3",
      "version": "1.3"
    }, {
      "name": "angularjs 1.2",
      "version": "1.2"
    }];

    $scope.age = 30;


    $scope.logger = function() {
      console.log('clicked');
    }

    $scope.ctrlScopeVariable = 'im in controller scope';
  })
```

Minor change to newDir:

```
function newDir (){
    return {
      scope: true, //you need this
      controller: function($scope){
        $scope.val= 'someval';
        console.log($scope.$parent.ctrlScopeVariable)
      },
      link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
       console.log(scope.$parent.name)
      }
    }
  }
```

And the last directive:

```
  function CustomerDetails() {

    var directive = {
      scope: {
        customer: '=',
        logger: '&',
        myNewAge: '@versionAge'
      },
      restrict: 'EA',
      require: ['^newDir'],
      controllerAs: 'cd',
      templateUrl: 'customer-details.html',
      link: linkFunction,
      controller: function($scope){
        console.log($scope.$parent.$parent.ctrlScopeVariable);

        var cd = this;
        cd.newval = 'new val';
      }
    };

    function linkFunction(scope, elem, attributes, controllers, transclude) {
      console.dir(controllers);
      scope.fromMainCtrl = scope.$parent.$parent.ctrlScopeVariable
    }

    return directive;
  }
```

[The Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5NHixXpRNpq7sIx02ef?p=preview)

I added a binding to the customer details template that passes in the $scope.ctrlScopeVariable from the main controller, so you can see the MainCtrl scope is accessible form the child directive.

In regards to `require`, the relevant documentation is here, I think:

> If it is necessary to reference the controller or any functions bound
>   to the controller's scope in the template, you can use the option
>   controllerAs to specify the name of the controller as an alias. The
>   directive needs to define a scope for this configuration to be used.
>   This is particularly useful in the case when the directive is used as
>   a component.
>
> Looking back at myPane's definition, notice the last argument in its
>   link function: tabsCtrl. When a directive requires a controller, it
>   receives that controller as the fourth argument of its link function.
>   Taking advantage of this, myPane can call the addPane function of
>   myTabs.

Essentially, you can use it to reference a parent controller on which you need to access some functions or something.  Notably, it becomes available under whatever alias you give it as the fourth argument of your link function.

**EDIT:**
In this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/s8NMQggOFeU3s0VvBJYA?p=preview) I added a function to the controller of newDir, required newDir in the CustomerDetail directive, and then called that function in the CustomerDetail link function:

CustomerDetails directive:

```
  //some stuff
  require: '^newDir',
  //some stuff
  link: function(scope, el, attr, newDirCtrl) {
    console.log(newDirCtrl.doubleNum(100));
  }
```

newDir controller:

```
  controller: function($scope){
    this.doubleNum = function(num) {
      return num*2
    }
    // some stuff
  }
```

Comment: I figured that too, wanted to understand what require is doing and how to use it.

Comment: Well I tried to do it based on that comment, can you modify your answer to show how that would work?

Comment: I was looking towards having the controllers scope inside the directive using require. I could not find any documentation as well.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare a variable as callback function:

```
var MainCtrlFn = function() { .... }
```

Then, you can set it as parameter to angularJS:

```
angular.module('plunker').controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrlFn);
```